# How to get difference between two dates in random colums in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have a spreadsheet with about 8000 rows where I have a rowID and 11 columns populated with dates. 
Each row has two dates and only two dates;
i.e., the other nine columns are blank. 
I want to calculate the difference between the two dates. 
It seems awfully inelegant to use a bunch of nested `IF` functions
to identify the two columns that are not blank. 
Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

[image: sample data (same as the below)]

```
| RowID    | Random1    | Random2    | Random3    | Random4    | Random5 | Random6    | Random7    | Random8    | Random9    | Random10   | Random11   |
|----------|------------|------------|------------|------------|---------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 63868570 |            | 10/11/2020 | 21/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 63882092 | 10/11/2020 |            | 15/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64387749 |            | 13/11/2020 |            | 10/11/2020 |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64455143 |            | 13/11/2020 |            |            |         |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |            |            |
| 64523533 |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |         | 18/11/2020 |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64609166 |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |         |            | 21/11/2020 |            |            |            |            |
| 64720036 | 13/11/2020 |            |            |            |         |            |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |
| 64738281 |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            | 21/11/2020 |            |            |
| 64778400 |            | 13/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64857763 |            | 13/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |            |
| 64934656 |            | 13/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64962687 |            | 10/11/2020 | 20/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64966825 |            | 15/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 64979371 | 19/11/2020 |            |            |            |         |            |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |
| 65054149 |            | 19/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |
| 65065845 |            | 13/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 65078532 |            | 13/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |            |
| 65092915 |            | 13/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 65210760 |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            | 19/11/2020 |            |            |
| 65211080 |            | 10/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            | 19/11/2020 |            |            |
| 65228686 |            | 10/11/2020 | 18/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 65366207 |            | 10/11/2020 | 20/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 65464270 |            | 19/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |
| 65464473 |            | 19/11/2020 |            |            |         |            |            |            |            |            | 10/11/2020 |
| 65480131 |            | 20/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
| 65505910 |            | 13/11/2020 | 10/11/2020 |            |         |            |            |            |            |            |            |
```

The dates are displayed above in dd/mm/yyyy format;
assume that they are stored as proper Excel dates.

Comment: you can format properly your table e.g. [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple approaches here:

1. `=MAX(B2:L2)-MIN(B2:L2)`

- This is probably the simplest formula, this works correctly if you always want to have positive results.
- In case you sometimes need to show negative difference too, then this won't work.

[image]

2. `=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(B2:L2,B2:L2<>""),{-1,1})`

- `FILTER` is a very powerful function, introduced recently and available in Office 365.
- With this formula you can also respect the order of dates and return negative difference if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
=LARGE(B2:L2,1)-LARGE(B2:L2,2)
```

`LARGE` will find the largest and second-largest values in the row. 
Based on your description of your worksheet,
they will be the two non-blank values.

Use the `DATEDIF` function if you want (if you have it).

Answer (score 0):

*This finds DAYS between two dates form Random Columns in Row:*

[image]

- Formula in cell L2:

  `=DAYS(SMALL(B2:K2,2),SMALL(B2:K2,1))`
- The DAYS function returns number of days between two dates, here SMALL finds the second & first  lowest.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*